# How to split data in one column to new column use awk in linux

Tags: awk

I have CSV file like this:

```
Operator_Code
A 
AA
AA,HB
AB,AX
AC
AD
AE,SJ,AX,VV
AF,SA,SP
AG
AG,SA
AK
AK,MA,CN,FA,AX
```

And I want to split every data who delimiter with comma to new column. Like this:

```
Operator_Code   col_02   col_03   col_04   col_05
A
AA
AA              HB
AB              AX
AC
AD
AE              SJ       AX       VV
AF              SA       SP
AG
AG              SA
AK
AK              MA       CN       FA        AX
```

How I should I do it with awk or other way is welcome.
Thanks advanced...

Comment: `tr ',' '\t' < file`

Comment: it's work like I need, and it can be another option for my case. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the max columns, may be this

```
# printf "Col1\tCol2\tCol3\tCol4\tCol5"; gawk -F","  '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}' infile
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5A
AA
AA      HB
AB      AX
AC
AD
AE      SJ      AX      VV
AF      SA      SP
AG
AG      SA
AK
AK      MA      CN      FA      AX
```

Comment: thanks u__ for the fast response. and it's work perfectly like I need.

Comment: or even `sed 's#,#\t#g' infile`

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="\t"} $1=$1' file`